# Unable to use internet when I am downloading a file

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

I'm unable to use internet when I am downloading a file. I've already completely did a fresh reinstall of the machine. I'm using OsX Mavericks on a macbook pro 13" late 2012 model.

I'm using a WiFi connection and 2 weeks ago I had a download speed of 8mb/s and now it hangs on 4.2mb/s and I am unable to open a webpage when downloading.

What could cause this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried it from a different wi-fi network, or does the problem persist across all locations?

Comment: I did use it on a different network, I even got a new modem installed today.

Comment: What is your WiFi profile. Hold the Alt key and press on WiFi icon.

Comment: What if you're using a different browser? Or isnt this the case? Doesn't make sense to stop the internet while you're downloading, sounds like software. Check your router priorities, it likes to handle bandwidth for better streaming and skype calls etc.